# How to link Bokeh inputs / controls to filter data? Can't work out how to make the input filter out values shown in the visual

Tags: python, bokeh

I've made a Bokeh visual with Python and am struggling to understand how to make controls / inputs change the data.

The Bokeh gallery has [an example which does what I'm after in a more advanced way](https://demo.bokeh.org/movies) and [also has the code](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/blob/master/examples/app/movies/main.py), and the thing I seem to be missing is `control.on_change('value', lambda attr, old, new: update())` , but I can't figure out what the update() and select functions are doing.

Here's a highly simplified version of where I'm stuck. I want to filter out entries with a 'Flights' value less than what's selected on the slider.

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_file, ColumnDataSource, show
from bokeh.models import Slider
from bokeh.layouts import column, layout

data = dict(
Flights =        [97, 34, 23, 6, 26, 97, 21, 92, 73, 10, 92, 14, 77, 4, 25, 48, 26, 39, 93],
Not_Cancelled =  [87, 63, 56, 38, 57, 63, 73, 56, 30, 23, 66, 47, 76, 15, 80, 78, 69, 87, 28],
OnTime_Arrivals= [21, 65, 86, 39, 32, 62, 46, 51, 17, 79, 64, 43, 54, 50, 47, 63, 54, 84, 79])
source = ColumnDataSource(data = data)
output_file('index.html')
p = figure()
p.circle('OnTime_Arrivals', 'Not_Cancelled', source = source, size = 20)

MinFlights = Slider(start=0, value = 50, end=100, step=1)
controls = [MinFlights]

inputs = column(*controls, width = 200)
l = layout([[inputs,p]])
show(l)
```

I'm also confused why some documentation indicates Javascript is required for callbacks, when I understood the premise of Bokeh to manage all the Javascript for you. Ideally I'd like to keep it all in Python.

Sorry for such a dumb question. I've spent the last two hours going crazy wondering why I can't get such a simple thing to work and am legit going bananas over here. Would sincerely appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2):

> I'm also confused why some documentation indicates Javascript is required for callbacks, when I understood the premise of Bokeh to manage all the Javascript for you. Ideally I'd like to keep it all in Python.

JavaScript is not required for callbacks, JavaScript is *possible* for callbacks. Real Python callbacks are always an option, but using them requires [running a Bokeh server application](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/server.html). Some use-cases might be better and more simply accomplished with a few lines of JavaScript instead, and some users would prefer that option. Bokeh affords both possibilities.

Your use-case could be accomplished either way. Here is a complete example that uses JS callbacks:

```py
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show
from bokeh.models import Slider, CustomJSFilter, CDSView, ColumnDataSource, CustomJS
from bokeh.layouts import column, layout

data = dict(Flights=[97, 34, 23, 6, 26, 97, 21, 92, 73, 10, 92, 14, 77, 4, 25, 48, 26, 39, 93],
            Not_Cancelled=[87, 63, 56, 38, 57, 63, 73, 56, 30, 23, 66, 47, 76, 15, 80, 78, 69, 87, 28],
            OnTime_Arrivals=[21, 65, 86, 39, 32, 62, 46, 51, 17, 79, 64, 43, 54, 50, 47, 63, 54, 84, 79])
source = ColumnDataSource(data=data)

MinFlights = Slider(start=0, value=50, end=100, step=1)

# this filter selects rows of data source that satisfy the constraint
custom_filter = CustomJSFilter(args=dict(slider=MinFlights), code="""
    const indices = []
    for (var i = 0; i < source.get_length(); i++) {
        if (source.data['Flights'][i] > slider.value) {
            indices.push(true)
        } else {
            indices.push(false)
        }
    }
    return indices
""")
view = CDSView(source=source, filters=[custom_filter])

# force a re-render when the slider changes
MinFlights.js_on_change('value', CustomJS(args=dict(source=source), code="""
   source.change.emit()
"""))

p = figure()
p.circle('OnTime_Arrivals', 'Not_Cancelled', source=source, view=view, size=20)

inputs = column(MinFlights, width=200)
show(layout([[inputs,p]]))
```

[image]

Comment: Wow this works really smoothly! Thank you so much!!

Unfortunately I don't know Javascript so it might be tricky expanding on your JS code with the more complex data set. Doesn't seem too complicated though... Could you please help me figure out how I could do this in python?

I'm trying to develop something which can be shared on a web page that'll work with a much larger data set, and perhaps do some basic calculations over a large set of numbers on the fly. I don't know much about establishing or running any kind of server either. Your advice? Bokeh Server or learn Javascript?

Comment: if the answer was helpful, and upvote or accept is appreciated. SO is not a good venue for dispensing advice (mods frown on and close questions like that). I would suggest going to the project discourse for that sort of discussion. https://discourse.bokeh.org/

Comment: This example that worked perfectly in 1.40 seems to be broken in 2.0.2 and I can't work out why. Could you please help me figure out how to get this working again?

Comment: @ChrisDixon I think there has been a bug introduced. Please file an issue on the tracker: https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues

Comment: Well, maybe not a bug, but something that could be warned about better. A `source` parameter is already implicitly passed in by Bokeh, so passing in again in the `args` dict is the problem. This stopped working in 2.0 because all `CustomJS` in Bokeh now enforce `use strict` mode. I have updated the answer above, but would still recommend and issue to advocate for something other than silent failure in this situation.